# Match/delete whole subgraph in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given there is a big graph in my database and I want to delete a whole subgraph of that, where I only know the starting node of this subgraph. Is it possible to write a cypher query to match and delete this whole subgraph?

Caveat: I don't know more of the subgraph as in which node it starts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can expand from a single node to all subgraph nodes via APOC Procedures [path expander](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_with_config), optionally with filters on the relationships or nodes to traverse, and with an optional max depth.

You need to use the expandConfig() procedure, and use NODE_GLOBAL uniqueness.

```
MATCH (s:Node)
WHERE s.name = 'start'
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(s, {uniqueness:'NODE_GLOBAL'}) YIELD path
WITH LAST(NODES(path)) as subgraphNode
...
```

Eventually there will be a subgraphNodes() procedure to wrap this to better highlight the functionality.