# Neo4j read all subgraphs without duplications Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been trying to get a subgraph based on a node query.
The query should ignore the relationship directions as long as all of the nodes in the subgraph are connected:
ex:
u1 -FRIEND-> u2 -FRIEND-> u3
u4 -FRIEND-> u5 -FRIEND-> u6

searching for u1 or u2 or u3, should return a set of: [u1,u2,u3]

I used the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (a:User)-[:FRIEND_OF*0..]-(b)
WHERE a.userId = 'some_id'
WITH a, collect(DISTINCT b) AS sets
RETURN DISTINCT sets
```

The problem is that I'm getting all of the set's permutations like:

```
DATA: u1 -FRIEND-> u2 -FRIEND-> u3
RETURN: [u1,u2,u3],[u1,u3,u2],[u2,u1,u3]...
```

how can I distinct the different sets to return only one permutation?

I also would like to support a case a user can be in different subgraphs so the response should be couple of subgraphs.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:

```
MATCH p=(a:User)-[:FRIEND_OF*0..]-(b)
WHERE a.userId = 'some_id'
WITH DISTINCT a, b
ORDER BY ID(b)
WITH a, COLLECT(b) AS sets
RETURN DISTINCT sets;
```

It gets distinct `a`/`b` pairs, orders the `b` nodes by native ID, puts the ordered nodes in collections, and finally returns distinct collections.

You may want to create an index for `:User(userId)` for better performance.

Comment: This is the right approach, though if your subgraphs are large and you're seeing performance hits, you may find [APOC's path expander](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42227632/92359) to be more efficient than the variable length pattern match when expanding out to match nodes in a subgraph.

Comment: thanks @cybersam - works like a charm.
also, thank you for the index tip.